# 7z missing volume .r00

Tags: linux, bash, 7-zip

Some .rar files by volume do not end in `.r00` or similar. then the following happens:

If I run in command line:

```
7z x -y -pfoo "file (1).rar"
```

And it is a file per volume, but the next volume is `file (2).rar` (with space)

```
ERRORS:
Missing volume: file (1).r00
```

However if the files are:

```
7z x -y -pfoo "file.part1.rar" # file.part2.rar, etc
```

7z unzips them well

Please correct me if I am wrong, but as I see it, this is more of a problem with the file name than the extension. Anyone have any ideas how to fix it?. Thanks

Workaround:

```
7z x -y -pfoo file*
```

Comment: How is 7z supposed to guess what the format is if it isn't rXX format?  I am not trying to be rude, only understand.  What extension to your other files in the volume have?

Comment: It is described in the question

Comment: Why using 7z for unpacking rar achhive? There is `unrar` tool available for that.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I know that, but the question is about 7z not about unrar